# What is a good universal naming syntax?

Tags: language-design, declarations

Lots of languages do not clearly separate the declaration of a variable, function or type from naming that entity, or if they do it does not have a uniform syntax. Consider C++:

- Naming a variable: `int foo = 42;` or `auto foo = int(42);`
- Naming a type: `class Bar { int x; };` or `using Bar = class { int x; };`
- Naming a function: `void baz() {};`, but `auto baz = [](){};` is *not* a function.

I think it would be worthwhile to separate the naming from declaring the entities, so for example it should be possible to define an unnamed variable/type/function, and then name it using a uniform syntax. For example, using the `name: entity` notation:

- `foo: int(42);`
- `Bar: class { x: int; };`
- `baz: (){};`

Omitting the `name:` part should then also be valid, and `name` and `entity` should be exchangeable. For example, currently in C++ you can write:

```
struct Bar { int x; };
constexpr int y = 42;
template<typename T = Bar, auto N = y> class Quux {…};
```

But the following is illegal:

```
template<typename T = struct { int x; }, auto N = 42> class Quux {…};
```

Because a `struct` declaration is not allowed in the template parameter list. Having a universal naming syntax would avoid these inconsistencies in the language.

I already see some issues with this: for example, the declaration `x: int` might be ambiguous; is this declaring a variable of type `int` (as in `int x;`), or is it declaring an alias for the type `int` (as in `using x = int;`)?

Are there any languages that already have such a way to name things, and what other problems would this have? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Welcome! It's not clear why you think it's worthwhile to separate the name from the declaration; is there a specific problem that doing this would solve, or is it just an aesthetic issue?

Comment: @kaya3-supportthestrike It's not just aesthetics; the goal is to avoid inconsistencies in languages. I've amended the question, I hope that makes it a bit more clear?

Comment: I see. But as far as I see, a language could very well support syntax like `template<typename T = struct { int x; }, auto N = 42> class Quux {…};` without needing a "universal naming syntax".

Answer (score 4):

## Assignment syntax

This is extra true for languages in which classes and functions *are* expressions (JavaScript technically counts, but some languages completely lack class/function *declarations*), although it's true that expressions and declarations aren't the same thing.

```js
const Foo = class {}
class {}

const bar = function () {}
function () {}
```

## OCaml syntax

Note that module syntax is the only special one here.

```ocaml
let val = ()
()

type t = a * b
a * b

module Name : optional_signature = struct <definition> end
module struct <definition> end
```

## JavaScript syntax

So, `<type> <name> <definition>`.
It's not "universal" in the sense that it's the same syntactic construct, but it's "universal" in the sense that names are specified the same way for all constructs.

For variables it's not *quite* the same...

```javascript
var foo = 42
let foo = 42
const foo = 42
42

var fn = () => {}
() => {}
```

... but for classes and functions it's just a matter of omitting the name

```js
class Bar {}
class {}

function baz() {}
function () {}
```

Comment: (if convention is to put all suggestions in a single answer please feel free to let me know)

Comment: Welcome to PLDI! Normally, all suggestions in a single answer is better than spread out over multiple answers. You might also want to add some detail about what the code does/is, as it seems a bit unclear right now.

Comment: fair enough, one answer per answer is just a habit i had... a bit weird though, bc if all suggestions in a single answer is the way to go then wouldn't a single CW answer for every question be the *most* conventional? or rather - what is the benefit of combining multiple suggestions together (but not all of them)?